# How do I get the date link for the archive?

Tags: wordpress

I use this code to get monthly articles archive

And I have a problem when I use `get_the_permalink();`  I don't get a link to the articles of the month

```
$all_posts = get_posts(array(
    'posts_per_page' => - 1, 
    'post_type' => 'news'

));

$ordered_posts = array();

foreach ($all_posts as $single)
{
    $year = mysql2date('Y', $single->post_date);
    $month = mysql2date('F', $single->post_date);
    $ordered_posts[$year][$month][] = $single;
}
foreach ($ordered_posts as $year => $months)
{ ?>

<?php foreach ($months as $month => $posts)
    { ?>    
    <a href="<?php get_the_permalink(); ?>">
                <div class="arch-year-month">                
                <div class="arch-month"><?php echo $month ?></div><div class="arch-year">  <?php echo $year ?></div></div></a>                                              
      <?php
    }
?>
   <?php
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

replace the code with `<a href="<?php echo get_month_link($year, date('m',strtotime($month))); ?>`this code, hope it will work. It is the specific month's link.

Comment: when using `get_the_permalink()`
He gets the link to the current page
Not a link to the articles list

Comment: I understand. Could you please replace the code with "<a href="<?php echo get_month_link($year, date('m',strtotime($month))); ?>">" this code, hope it will work for you as it is linked me to the specific year's month link.

Comment: It gets duplicate value https://prnt.sc/w6j5-EihpyKD
I found another solution, and posted it in the same post

Answer (score 0):

I found this solution,

```
$all_posts = get_posts(array(
  'posts_per_page' => -1, 
  'post_type' => 'news'

));



$myMonth = array();
foreach ($all_posts as $single) {
 $month = mysql2date('F', $single->post_date);
 $month_number = mysql2date('m', $single->post_date);
 $myMonth[$month] = $month_number;
}



$ordered_posts = array();
foreach ($all_posts as $single) {
  $year  = mysql2date('Y', $single->post_date);
  $month = mysql2date('F', $single->post_date);
  $month_number = mysql2date('m', $single->post_date);

  $ordered_posts[$year][$month][] = $single;
  
}

foreach ($ordered_posts as $year => $months) {
foreach ($months as $month => $posts ) { 
?>

<?php 

  ?>
    <a href="/news-date/<?php echo $year ?>/<?php echo $myMonth[$month]; ?>">
                <div class="arch-year-month">
                 
                <div class="arch-month"><?php echo $month ?></div><div class="arch-year">  <?php echo $year ?>
                </div>
                </div>
                </a>
                
                
                
      <?php
      } 
    
} 
?>
```